# Does a free group $F$ of finite rank $n$ have finitely many retracts (as a subgroup)?

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism, free-groups, retraction

A subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ is called a retract of $G$ if there exists an epimorphism $r:G\to H$ such that $r(h)=h$ for all $h\in H$.

Does a free group $F$ of finite rank $n$ have finitely many retracts (as a subgroup)? Does a retract of a free group $F$ of finite rank have a specific form?

What I've tried: Let $G=\mathbb{Z}$. Let $H\neq 1$ be a retract of $G$. Then there is an epimorphism $r:G\to H$ such that $r(h)=h$ for all $h\in H$. So $G=H\ltimes \mathrm{ker}(r)$. Since $\mathrm{ker}(r)\lhd G$, if $\mathrm{ker}(r)\neq 1$, then we have $\mathrm{ker}(r)=n\mathbb{Z}$, hence $H\cong \mathbb{Z}_n$ which is a contradiction to the fact that $H$ is a subgroup of free group $\mathbb{Z}$. Thus $\mathrm{ker}(r)=1$, and then $H=\mathbb{Z}$. We conclude that either $H=1$ or $H=G$.

Comment: For more context, see also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4486028/does-finitely-generated-groups-have-finitely-many-finite-retracts), and [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/130992/is-a-retract-of-a-group-of-type-f-n-again-of-this-type).

Comment: Infinitely many unless $n\le 1$: Each free factor of $F_n$ is a retract and there are infinitely many free factors.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: An interesting question is whether every retract is a free factor. If so, there are only finitely many retracts up to the action of $Aut(F_n)$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan That's a really question. I'll consider it and  try to prove it. Thanks very much for the comment.

Comment: My question has a negative answer: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/25944/does-every-retraction-of-free-groups-arise-from-projection-to-a-subset-of-a-free

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I close this question by giving the answer of @MoisheKohan in the comments: For $n\geq 2$, the statement is false because each free factor of $F_n$ is a retract and there are infinitely many free factors. Thanks to @MoisheKohan for pointing this out.